# use SUM in alias

Tags: php, sql

I want to use SUM function in alias 
please look at following code i hope you understand it:

```
     SELECT PATIENTS.NAME,
       PATIENTS.FAMILY,
       COST.COST,
       COST.REALDATEYEAR,
       COST.REALDATEMONTH,
       COST.REALDATEDAY,
       CONTRACTS.ID,
       CONTRACTS.FRANSHIZ AS CO1,
       PATIENTS.COMPANY,
       CONTRACTS.COMPANY,
       COST.TYPE,
       TARRIFS.ID,
       TARRIFS.ACTION,
       TARRIFS.COST       AS CO
  FROM PATIENTS
 INNER JOIN COST
 INNER JOIN CONTRACTS
 INNER JOIN TARRIFS
    ON PATIENTS.SINGLE_ID = COST.SINGLE_ID
   AND COST.TYPE = TARRIFS.ID
   AND CONTRACTS.ID = PATIENTS.COMPANY
```

i want to use SUM for co1 and co,

Comment: Show us your input and expected output.

Comment: How are you grouping the rows for the purposes of the sum?

Comment: You'll get (at least) one row for each CONTRACTS.ID, how do you want to sum CONTRACTS.FRANSHIZ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` when using `SUM`.

Your query something like this.

```
SELECT PATIENTS.NAME,
       PATIENTS.FAMILY,
       COST.COST,
       COST.REALDATEYEAR,
       COST.REALDATEMONTH,
       COST.REALDATEDAY,
       CONTRACTS.ID,
       SUM(CONTRACTS.FRANSHIZ) AS CO1,
       PATIENTS.COMPANY,
       CONTRACTS.COMPANY,
       COST.TYPE,
       TARRIFS.ID,
       TARRIFS.ACTION,
       TARRIFS.COST AS CO
  FROM PATIENTS
 INNER JOIN COST
 INNER JOIN CONTRACTS
 INNER JOIN TARRIFS
    ON PATIENTS.SINGLE_ID = COST.SINGLE_ID
   AND COST.TYPE = TARRIFS.ID
   AND CONTRACTS.ID = PATIENTS.COMPANY
 GROUP BY CONTRACTS.FRANSHIZ
```

Comment: as we are selecting few more other columns also, I think, we should list down them also in `group by` clause .. right?

Comment: yes, we need to list down them also. we are not much aware about structure and which column need grouping so we are giving just idea to user. @pratikgarg

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.